# Binomial coefficients sum problem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am trying to answer the following problem but I barely understand the question and I've no idea how to proceed.

Calculate the value of $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n 5^k\binom nk$ for cases where $n = 1,\;2,\;3$.

Could somebody please give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll want to recall the binomial expansion formula:

$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k a^k b^{n-k}$$

Consider values of $a,b$ that help you match the formula you wish to calculate. For example, letting $b=1$ (and thus getting rid of the $b^{n-k}$ term) is quite tempting...

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we have $$\sum_{k=0}^n5^k\binom nk=\sum_{k=0}^n5^k1^{n-k}\binom nk=(5+1)^n=6^n.$$ So, plugging $n=1,2,3$, we get $\boxed{6,36,216}$.